# Custom keyboard layout in sandboxed app?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout, sandbox, omnigraffle

I have a [TN2056](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2056/_index.html) Installable Keyboard Layout that I’ve placed in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. It is the default keyboard layout, and is used by all apps.

But now with the [new version of OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/releasenotes/omnigraffle-mac) that runs in the sandbox, I am unable to use it. It shows up in the input menu but nothing happens when I click it; I get the default US English instead. I’m guessing it’s a sandbox problem, but it does show up in `~/Library/Containers/com.omnigroup.OmniGraffle6/Data/Library/Keyboard Layouts`.

How can I use a custom keyboard layout in OmniGraffle 6?

Comment: Try moving the keyboard layout to /Library/Keyboard Layouts/ and restarting. Keyboard layouts in the user library can't be selected in password dialogs or on the login window.